# Using a dictionary, how do I keep Values and Keys together after sorting the keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary, with a name (key) and a score (value) where I remove all of the values, and then sort them using a merge sort. But how do I then make a new dictionary with the new sorted list of values but with their original key if that makes sense?

I have searched around before asking, and only really found ways to sort a dictionary as a whole, but I want to use a merge sort I have made, which I do not think is possible with a dictionary. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can search back the keys, one by one, with a dictionary comprehension like `{k: a[k] for k in sorted(a)}`. Alternatively, you can sort `a.items()` which would keep the key-value pairs in the format of tuples:

```
>>> a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

# using sorted(a.items()) (keys and values reserved)

>>> sorted(a.items())
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]

>>> {k: v for k, v in sorted(a.items())}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

# using sorted(a) (only keys reserved)

>>> [(k, a[k]) for k in sorted(a)]
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]

>>> {k: a[k] for k in sorted(a)}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, it doesn't sort?

Comment: A dictionary won't retain it's order, so you'll need to use an OrderedDict which is part of the collections module. If you really want to use your merge sort, then sort it into a list of tuples like Uriel has done above, and create the OrderedDict with: `d = OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ...])`

Comment: Yeah I get what you mean, but I have no idea how I would go about this, I am not very experienced in python. Thanks anyway though :)

Comment: @RobertSeaman actually, in python 3.6 dictionaries **are** ordered.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that dictionaries are ordered in python 3.6! Thanks @Uriel!

Comment: @Nimrodian - in python versions lower than 3.6 - `d = OrderedDict([(k, your_dict[k]) for k in your_merge_sort_function(your_dict)])`